# Why was the term "discrete" used in discrete logarithm?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, terminology

Is there anything especially "discrete" about a discrete logarithm? This is not a question of what is a discrete logarithm or why the discrete logarithm problem is an "intractable problem" given certain circumstances. I'm just trying to determine if there's some additional meaning to the term "discrete" as it's used in name discrete logarithm?

The definition of "discrete" is "individually separate and distinct". Could it be that the term "discrete" is a reference to the least non-negative residues of a modulus or the order of points for a particular cyclic group on an elliptic curve?

Comment: Traditional logarithm: answer is a real or complex number. Discrete logarithm: answer is an element of a finite set $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: See also [discrete mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics)

Comment: That's a pretty discreet information.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The word discrete is used as an antonym of 'continuous', that is, it is the normal logarithmic problem, just over a discrete group.

The standard logarithmic problem is over the infinite group $\mathbb{R}^*$, this group is called 'continuous', because for any element $x$, there are other elements that are arbitrarily close to it.

The discrete logarithmic problem is over a finite group (for example, $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$); in contrast to $\mathbb{R}^*$, we don't have group elements arbitrarily close together; we call this type of group 'discrete'.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that the fact that the group is discrete in a discrete logarithm, isn't what makes them useful in say DH, but instead other properties? For example, a useful property of a discrete group (in connection with DH) when the modulus and base are chosen wisely is that computing the exponent used to exponentiate a power can be made computationally infeasible (e.g. DLP)? Or is there some connection between the non-continuous nature of the discrete group that enables the intractability of DLP?

Comment: When I said "made computationally infeasible (e.g. DLP)?" It should have been "made computationally infeasible to reverse (e.g. DLP)?"

Comment: yes, being discrete is not the "core reason" why dlp can be hard - although note that if we are to ever use the crypto we build on a computer, things better be discrete - at best, we can only approximate a continuous primitive in a discrete way.

Comment: @JohnGalt The hard part of the DLP is the modular reduction "hiding" how many times you've "wrapped around". Without modular reduction, you can do some sort of "binary search" to get accurate lower/upper bounds to the discrete log rather efficiently.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau Not being sarcastic here (just want to make sure I understand), when you say not the "core reason" is there even a "non-core" reason why the fact that the group being discrete adds to DLP? And with regard to "better be discrete", I think you're saying that with a computer we don't want things like repeating decimals which are eliminated if we use a discrete set of integers?

Comment: my point is just the following: when you manipulate concrete number on your computer, they will have to come from some discrete structure, since you cannot represent numbers with arbitrary precision (hence you cannot accurately represent elements of a continuous set such as the reals). Hence, you will need your problem to be hard over a discrete structure anyway, even though being discrete is not what makes it hard.

Comment: @Mark That makes sense. I also found that counting the digits of the power and then multiplying those digits by $log_{10}(base used to exponentiate)$ and the digits-1 by the same $log_{10}(base used to exponentiate)$ provides a limited number of test cases to compute the log.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau This isn't precisely true. Any computable number has a finite-length turing machine that, on input $n$, will output the $n$th digit of the number. This can be viewed as a finite-length representation of the number. As an example, there are formula for $\pi$ (such as the BBP formula) that compute the $i$th digit without computing all smaller digits. This is definitely a different notion of "representation" than simply storing the literal value in memory, but the computable numbers are notably not discrete (they contain $\mathbb{Q}$ as a sub-field).

Comment: @Mark you are perfectly right, although for the purpose of getting a high level intuition regarding this specific question (regarding discrete log), I felt like my answer would provide one. We could perhaps work with problems over more general structures through appropriate representations, though I believe this has never been done in Cryptography.

Comment: @JohnGalt: To add a bit to Mark and GeoffroyCouteau's comments . . . in principle, if we had a computer that could store arbitrary real numbers and perform infinite-precision math on them, then we could do the equivalent of modular reduction by (for example) just dropping the integer part and taking the fractional part. (If all you knew was that *n* is an integer in [0, *N*) and the fractional part of eⁿ was 0.1254123452312..., it would be very hard to find *n*.) So you can see that the discreteness really isn't what makes the discrete logarithm hard to compute.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau "you cannot represent numbers with arbitrary precision" You cannot represent real numbers with *infinite* precision, but it is possible to represent them with *arbitrary* precision.

Comment: "The standard logarithmic problem is over the infinite group R∗ ... The discrete logarithmic problem is over a finite group" However, an infinite group can still be discrete.

Comment: @Acccumulation what would be an example of an infinite group that is still discrete?

Comment: @JohnGalt The simplest would be the integers.

Comment: @Acccumulation (not being argumentative) If integers defined as {...-2,-1,0,1,2...} and group operation is multiplication as is the case with exponentiation, can all integers be considered a group? For example, 0 doesn't have an inverse. But I may be confusing the term "group" with something different?

Comment: @JohnGalt Integers can be treated as being a group with addition as the group operation, or a ring with addition and multiplication.

Answer (score 13):

While I agree completely with poncho's answer, this other viewpoint might be useful.
Specifically, I think a better comparison isn't between $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ and $\mathbb{R}^*$, but with $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ and $S^1$. We can view $S^1 \cong \{z\in\mathbb{C} \mid |z| = 1\}$. It's not hard to show that any $z\in S^1$ is able to be written as $z = \exp(2\pi i t)$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (we don't strictly need the factor $2\pi$ here, but it's traditional). Due to $\exp(x)$ being periodic, it's in fact enough to have $t\in[0,1)$.

This has an obvious group structure, in that:
$$\exp(2\pi i t_0)\exp(2\pi i t_1) = \exp(2\pi i (t_0+t_1))$$
If we're making the restriction that $t_i\in[0,1)$, then we have to take $t_0+t_1\mod 1$, but this is fairly standard.

More than just having an obvious group structure, we actually have that any $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ injects into it.
Specifically, we always have:
$$
\phi_p:\mathbb{Z}_p^*\to S^1,\quad \phi_p(x) = \exp(2\pi i x/(p-1))
$$
Here, $p-1$ in the denominator is because $|\mathbb{Z}_p^*| = p-1$.
We can define the discrete logarithm problem for both of these groups in the standard way (here, it's important to restrict $t_i\in[0, 1)$ if we want a unique answer).
Then, we can relate these problems to each via the aforementioned injection.
Through this image, we see that $S^1$ is "continuous" in the sense that it takes up the full circle, but the image of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ in $S^1$ will always be "discrete" --- there will *always* be "some space" between points (they can't get arbitrarily close).

Comment: A nice feature of this example is that because S1 can readily support an operator that raises values to a fractional power, one can define log functions in terms of that.  Because for most pairs of (x,z) there would generally be many exponent values such that x to the power y would yield z, there are many possible functions which use different ways to select *which* power y gets used.  A continuous-log function might select a y in S1, while a discrete-log function would select the smallest y in Z.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the other answers, (as mentioned in some of the comments) it is exactly the discreteness of the discrete log problem is that makes it (for some parameter choices) hard. Computing $y = \log_{a}(x)$ is the same as solving the equation $a^y = x$ for $y$. In the non-discrete case, $y \mapsto a^y$ is a monotonically increasing (if $a > 1$) continuous function. Thus, you can (in the absence of even more efficient methods) use the bisection method to solve for $y$. When you have a value $y$ for which $a^y$ is close to the target $x$ then you know that $y$ is close to the value you seek. Knowing when you are close to a solution is very useful information.

In the discrete case, there is no corresponding notion of closeness. Say if for some reason you wanted to compute the base-$19$ discrete log of $7155$ (mod $34591$) and somehow find that $19^{481} = 7156$ (mod $34591$). Does this imply that $\log_{19}(7155)$ is close to $481$? Not at all. The actual value is $\log_{19}(7155) = 28544$. It is much harder to find a solution when you can't tell when you are close.

Comment: Is "Knowing when you are close to a solution is very useful information." related to knowing when the value of something is greater than the value of another? That is, in a binary search algorithm used to calculate a log from an exponentiated power, it is critical to know the upper and lower limits of the target power on each test. Each iteration gets you closer and closer to the solution until the solution is reached. If you can't determine whether the test is greater than (or less than) the target, the search doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnGalt They are closely related (because the standard topology on R is the order topology) but they are not the same thing. Order definitely plays a role here, but continuity can be used to solve equations even when there isn't a clear order (C does not have an order topology). Certainly the bisection method for finding a real root of a continuous function has the same basic logic as a binary search.